# Error when creating Elsif Trigger Before Update

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am creating trigger when `Selisih` column is equal to `0`, then `Status` column become `'Partial'`. If `QtyInternalUse` column is equal to `QtyRequested`, then `Status` column is `Completed`, else, it is `Not Issued`

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TG_STATUSINREQ
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON M_INTERNALREQUESTERLINE
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (:new.Selisih <> 0 ) THEN
       :new.Status := 'Partial';
    ELSIF :new.QtyInternalUse := :new.QtyRequested THEN
       :new.Status := 'Completed';
    ELSE
       :new.Status := 'Not Issued';
    END IF;
    END;
```

I've tried execute it and there's error that says

```
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
         like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset
         The symbol "* was inserted before "=" to continue.
```

I've tried deleting `:` in `=` but still it won't work. How can I fix this?

**REVISION**

I have updated the logic and the := . The trigger was created and it's like this :

```
BEGIN

IF (:new.QtyInternalUse = 0 ) THEN

   :new.Status := 'Not Issued';

ELSIF :new.QtyInternalUse = :new.QtyRequested THEN

   :new.Status := 'Completed';

ELSE

   :new.Status := 'Partial';

END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Which colon(s) did you remove?  `:=` is assignment.  `=` is an equality test.  `:new.QtyInternalUse := :new.QtyRequested` should be an equality test not an assignment so you should be using `=` rather than `:=` there.  If you are still getting an error after fixing that, edit your question to show the updated code and the new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty easy google-resolve. Still here you go.

```
ELSIF :new.QtyInternalUse := :new.QtyRequested THEN
```

You are trying to compare but using assignment operator[:=]. Use equals[=] in stead that will resolve your problem.

```
ELSIF :new.QtyInternalUse = :new.QtyRequested THEN
```